# CSS after and before

Tags: css

[image]HTML :

```
<h3> <span>What have you missed </span></h3>
```

CSS :

```
h3 {color:#c8352e; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:20px; font-weight:900; font-family:arial,'sans-serif'; position:relative; padding-left:22px;}

    h3:before, h3:after {position: absolute; content: ""; height: 4px; top: 50%; border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
    h3:before {width:15px; left:0;}
    h3:after {width:60%;}
    h3 span {display: inline-block;padding-right: 10px;}
```

I need these line effect with help of css.
[image]

Comment: The answers here are suspect in that they, and you, use older CSS notation which shouldn't be used. Always use double colons `::before` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of change maybe a precision and production label output

```css
h3 {
  color: #c8352e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: arial, "sans-serif";
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

h3::before,
h3::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 4px double #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

h3::before {
  width: 15px;
  left: 0;
}

h3::after {
  width: 50%;
}

h3 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h3><span>What have you missed </span></h3>
```

Comment: Your properties are old. The correct way to use them is with double colons `::before` and `::after` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: **Thanks Momin**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rob !

Answer (score 0):

I used double instead of solid.Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
h3 {color:#c8352e; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:20px; font-weight:900; font-family:arial,'sans-serif'; position:relative; padding-left:22px;}

    h3:before, h3:after {position: absolute; content: ""; height: 4px; top: 50%; border-top: 4px double #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
    h3:before {width:15px; left:0;}
    h3:after {width:60%;}
    h3 span {display: inline-block;padding-right: 10px;}
   
</style>
<body>
<h3 ><span>What have you missed </span></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The current, modern notation is two colons, not one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: ** Thanks Hema **

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```css
.subtitle {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
.fancy {
  line-height: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.fancy h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
}
.fancy h3::before,
.fancy h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
}
.fancy h3::before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.fancy h3::after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtitle fancy"><h3>what have you missed!</h3></div>
```

Comment: The current, modern notation in CSS is with two colons, not one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this>>>>>>>>>>

#### what have you missed!

```
.subtitle {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
.fancy {
  line-height: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.fancy h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
}
.fancy h3::before,
.fancy h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
}
.fancy h3::before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.fancy h3::after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Thakur92411/pen/yzPJbO

Answer (score 0):

CSS `before` and `after` work like this

Selector:: before{CSS here} so your CSS should be like this

```
h3 {color:#c8352e; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:20px; font-weight:900; font-family:arial,'sans-serif'; position:relative; padding-left:22px;}

h3::before, h3::after {position: absolute; content: "g"; height: 4px; top: 50%; border-top:10px solid #ccc; border-bottom:10px solid #ccc; color:blue; }
 h3 ::before {width:15px; left:0;}
h3 ::after {width:60%;}
h3 span {display: inline-block;padding-right: 10px;}
```